# Highcharts YAxis Title is smudged

Tags: html, css, highcharts

I am trying to apply a title to YAxis of my chart, it looks smudged (overlaps on each other) on the screen, whereas my other titles looks just fine.

My code :

```
        yAxis: [{
           title: {
                text : 'User Count',
                margin : 60,
                style : {
                    fontWeight : '100%',
                    fontFamily : 'verdana'
                 }
               }
        }],

 series: [{
            data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,3,8,1,10,4,11]
        }]
    });
});
```

Sample: I get this in IE9, but not in FF and chrome. Please suggest a solution. I have been stuck with this for months. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle that shows the overlapping?

Comment: For me, looks like properly http://jsfiddle.net/ojrkzb4s/. Which browser do you use?

Comment: I cannot recreate the problem in FF or chrome. I think this is an IE Issue, when i use IE 9 standard [Document mode], it looks fine.
Whereas in Browser mode, the title looks blurry.

Comment: At this moment this is related with two bugs [ie7/8](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/663) and [IE10](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1711)